# Updating an array returned by a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've been trying to implement some card game using Javascript. In the snippet below, I simply want to pull two cards from the top of the deck and give it to the player (simplified logic below)

```js
function deck() {
    var faceCards = [['jack', 11],['queen', 12],['king', 13]];
    return faceCards;
}
function removeCard() {
    var singleCard = deck().pop();
    var faceValue = singleCard[0];
    return faceValue;
}
var cardPair = [removeCard(),removeCard()];
console.log(cardPair);
```

However the **faceCards** array is still the same even after popping off its cards which means that the next card will be the same as well as seen in cardPair array.

> I need to mirror the effects I used inside of the
>   removeCard() function to reflect back in the deck() function.

I suppose I could either create the faceCards array in the global scope or use 'this' in some way (which I don't really want as I'm not much familiar with it). How can I update one function from inside another function? Thank you very much for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
var singleCard = deck().pop()
```

The call to `deck()` creates a *new* array of cards every time it's called, and doesn't repeatedly return the same array.

If you don't want to go full OO yet, consider at least passing the deck as a parameter to the `removeCard()` function, i.e.

```
function removeCard(deck) {
    var singleCard = deck.pop();
    var faceValue = singleCard[0];
    return faceValue;
}

var deck = newDeck();
var pair = [ removeCard(deck), removeCard(deck) ];
```

but ultimately you *should* longer term be going for a full OO solution, where your usage might then become:

```
var deck = new Deck();
var pair = [ deck.takeCard(), deck.takeCard() ];
```

implementation of this is out of scope of this particular question.

Comment: @BijayTimilsina well, really you _should_ be going full OO

Comment: @Alnitak what does that mean? How is it even applicable?

Comment: "well, really you should be going full OO"

Comment: @AluanHaddad I mean he really should be encapsulating the behaviour of a `Deck` of cards in a JS class, as the OP alluded to by his mention of `this` in the question.

Comment: There is no need for a class at all. A useful and simple improvement would be to place the `removeCard` function inside the `deck` function. Then `return { removeCard, otherDeckManipulators };`

Comment: @AluanHaddad  and how would he access that function?

Comment: `var d = deck(); var cardPair = [d.removeCard(), d.removeCard()];`

Comment: @AluanHaddad but `deck()` _returns an array_.  If you want it to return an _object that contains methods_ then _you just created a class_ !!

Comment: A class is ridiculous here. You aren't even using `this`, not that you should. But you are introducing needless complexity

Comment: In this case it is the exact same thing, you don't even use instance state. You just shoved `new` in front of the function.

Comment: @Alnitak so the mistake I'm making is that calling deck().pop() makes new instance(??) of the main deck() every time which are all the same right? so how does passing a variable deck into the removeCard() solve this? thank you

Comment: @BijayTimilsina because you should only call `deck()` (to make the new deck once) and then you just pass a _reference_ to that deck each time you want to remove a card

Comment: @AluanHaddad _"implementation of this is out of scope of this particular question."_ - but would in most cases result in use of `this`, unless the internal state was maintained in lexically scoped private variables.

Comment: Lexical scoping is preferable.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's a religious viewpoint.  Sometimes it's preferred, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: I can guarantee that if something as fundamental as the difference between objects created by different invocations of a function is being missed, assigning a function to the prototype property of another function, and then pretending it is a class will not will not reduce confusion.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I never mentioned the prototype.  In pre-ES6 code I wouldn't usually bother using it myself either, and for an object of which few instances are expected would just assign the methods as properties of `this` in the constructor function.

Comment: If this is an ES2015 example you should be using block scoped bindings. Also, ES6 classes just paper over this pattern. People do stupid things like write subtypes of `Error` and they think `instanceof` is a type test. And then they get frustrated because they can't have multiple catch blocks. All for no reason

Comment: @AluanHaddad  Whatever.  Either way your downvote for my making a  recommendation for proper OO encapsulation when you yourself are recommending a thin OO wrapper seems somewhat egregious.

Comment: Using a factory would provide true encapsulation because you have lexical scoping. There is no privacy with classes. Not yet.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes, I know that, you know that.  There's _many, many_ ways of doing OO in JavaScript, and I actually quite like to use lexical scoping with member functions closed over those variables.  However I usually still do that within the context of a true constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new array every time you run `deck()`. Try saving the deck in an array and running `pop` on this:

```js
function deck() {
    var faceCards = [['jack', 11],['queen', 12],['king', 13]];
    return faceCards;
}
function removeCard(fromDeck) {
    var singleCard = fromDeck.pop();
    var faceValue = singleCard[0];
    return faceValue;
}
var thisDeck = deck();
var cardPair = [removeCard(thisDeck),removeCard(thisDeck)];
console.log(cardPair);
```

Comment: so I suppose here I'm just editing a duplicate copy of the main deck stored in a variable thisDeck right? so when I change stuffs, the changes are only happening in thisDeck but not faceCards right?

Comment: this is a poor implementation - the `removeCard()` function shouldn't be relying on any externally scoped variables.  What happens (for example) if you want to use _two decks_... ?

Comment: @BijayTimilsina That's correct, yes you're manipulating `thisDeck` there, and using the `deck` function to just give you the original deck once, you don't need to recall it until you want to "shuffle" or build a new deck again. So the "live" deck is in that var, yes.

Comment: @Alnitak good point, nothing about 2 decks was mentioned though, and I was just trying to highlight that OP was editing a new array each time, not making edits in the same variable :)

Comment: @Stu right, but the correct implementation would be to _pass the deck_, not modify a variable outside of the function's scope

Comment: @Alnitak, true; something like the updated, feel free to update it yourself!